# AngularJS multiple ngApps each with its own ngRoute definitions, lazyloaded and bootstrapped on one page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angular-routing

My question comes from the need to lazy load different/separate ngApps on one page(bootstrapping them with angular.bootstrap), each of them using its own ngRoute definitions(defined in such a way that they do not overlap each other).

Now I have a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7A9bc3bDUyAXIS13JMZ?p=preview) example and all seems to function well, but somehow I have the feeling that this is not the correct approach so that's why Im asking here for advice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 well" id="app1">
      <h3>App1</h3>
      <a href="#/app1/1">Route 1</a>
      <a href="#/app1/2">Route 2</a>
      <a href="#/app1/3">Route 3</a>
      <div class="well" ng-view></div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6 well" id="app2">
      <h3>App2</h3>
      <a href="#/app2/1">Route 1</a>
      <a href="#/app2/2">Route 2</a>
      <a href="#/app2/3">Route 3</a>
      <div class="well" ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app1 = angular.module('app1', ['ngRoute']);
    app1
      .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/:app/:param', {
            template: 'app = {{app}}, param = {{param}}',
            controller: 'Ctrl1'
          })
      })
      .controller("Ctrl1",['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope,$routeParams) {
        $scope.app = $routeParams.app;
        $scope.param = $routeParams.param;
      }]);

    var app2 = angular.module('app2', ['ngRoute']);
    app2
      .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/:app/:param', {
            template: 'app = {{app}}, param = {{param}}',
            controller: 'Ctrl2'
          })
      })
      .controller("Ctrl2", ['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope,$routeParams) {
        $scope.app = $routeParams.app;
        $scope.param = $routeParams.param;
      }]);

    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app1"), ['app1']);
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app2"), ['app2']);
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7A9bc3bDUyAXIS13JMZ?p=preview

FYI: I have already checked out ui-router to load separate states on one page, but it all requires for the source code to be loaded upfront(and have a single app.config with all routes in it) which is something I do not want as the Project is quite huge. So for the sake of keeping it simple and modular Im looking for something like the above example.

UPDATE to answer HockeyJ question:
OK I will try to keep this as short as possible. Very basically put - as I said the project could potentially become quite huge, from source code and module dependency perspective. This is why I want to make it in such a way, that each module can be totally separate App, able to be injected at any place and tested separately(thats not really an issue with AnJS). In the same time however the whole project, should be a single page app. As such there should not be screen reloads(to load an App jscript files) etc. Hence comes the lazy loading of scripts on demand and bootstrapping apps to DOM elems. The only possible intersection point of all apps is the URL routing which has strict naming convention for routes i.e. /reports/whatever ; /transactions/whatever etc. and should be managed by ngRoute.

Comment: Please could you explain a little more on what you are trying to achieve? If it's just modularity of components, could you use directives instead of creating whole apps? This is a good tutorial on the matter - http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/07/dont-fear-directives-in-angular-js/ . Personally, I don't like sammy and like to stick purely with Angular, but that's personal opinion.

Comment: I've updated the main thread with an answer to your question.

Comment: something I noticed in the plunkr is that if you click route1 -> route2 -> then route1 again it triggers an infinite $digest loop as the state of app1 has not actually changed. Which in a way answers my question that perhaps angular was not designed with such usage in mind.

Comment: [Overmind](https://github.com/geddski/overmind) does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak just  wrote about the same thing and saw your comment

Comment: I saw the Overmind in the last ng-newsletter and more or less it suits my needs but the below limitation ad far as I understood brings me back to the main question of multiple apps on one page: Limitations

Overmind.js is a replacement for ng-view, and currently assumes a single main content area. Luckily your apps can bootstrap other apps where needed. For example when the user clicks on a chat icon, the nav app could load & bootstrap the chat app into a sidbar area.

Comment: And one more setback of overmind again as far as I understood is that you would have to define your routes in the main overmind app, and per app definitions of different routes would probably not work.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATED:

Checkout [overmind](https://github.com/geddski/overmind) project for angular and the demo [here](http://geddski.github.io/overmind)

> Shows a project broken up into several apps: nav, home, profile, and admin. The nav app is always on the page and is the only app bootstrapped on pageload.

Just take routing out of angular and use something like sammy.js , history.js etc for client side routing.

Use

```
angular.bootstrap(module, node)
```

in the routes of your sammy handlers

Also you might want to take a look at react.js (with or without flux) and tide it up with sammy the same way. Consider this example from todombc : https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/react

Comment: This is a working solution but I want to keep external libs to a minimum, and further more I would like to make use of angular-ngRouting's other features. And this does not answer is the above approach(even though working) wrong from architectural point of view.